# If google chrome uses WebKit, can I create my own "chrome"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, rendering

Google chrome browser uses WebKit for HTML/CSS/JavaScript/etc... rendering, which means Google  Inc. used something available to everyone, and didn't create anything on their own

So, if WebKit is free, I can use it to create my own browser with same speed as chrome?
Did Google only create an interface and not develop the rendering engine?

Comment: Here's a nice example for windows https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftRbU9GPNng and more to the point this indian kid's video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpNzQq8zmuk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you are right, but also keep in mind google chrome uses V8 as their javascript-engine. And you might extend this line of thought for other parts needed to build a fully functioning browser.
You'd also need (cross platform) code to launch and display your 'chrome' ui and have it interact with the os.

Comment: Agree. Adding to that: not only Chrome uses this "concept". Firefox uses Gecko (which you could use), IE uses Trident (closed source, who cares :P ) and Opera uses... wait, Opera went to Webkit :P But it *used to* use Presto. See, for example, [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browser_engines) for more engines and links to other relevant topics.

Comment: yes, there are also multi-engine browsers (that combine webkit and trident and gecko and ... take your pick).

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can build your own browser. But, there are multiple things that make Google Chrome a better browser. The rendering Engine maybe opensourced. But, there are multiple other things you need to consider when seeing a browser. This is the abstract architecture of a browser of which Webkit is only the rendering engine.

[image: browse architecture]

See this blogpost and try to understand the various things browser does and engines they use.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/

There are many browsers based on Chromium like Rockmelt.

Disclaimer: This is the image from the html5rocks blog.